# Field Editor: Unable to load the requested class: services_json

Tags: field-editor

Since i'm not getting any response in the official support forum for FIELD EDITOR I decided to repeat the question over here in the hope someone out there knows how to solve this.

Since i started development on a ee 2.8.1 system i’m getting a "Unable to load the requested class: services_json" error when i try to save changes to my custom field group using FIELD EDITOR.

Googling the error helped me find a similar error in the Zoo Flex Admin add-on but the solutions posted there didn't help me fix this issue.
http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/zoo-flexible-admin/viewthread/12713

Do you have any clue how to fix this?

Greets,
Bas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Search your Field Editor files for this line:

```
$this->EE->load->library('services_json');
```

I believe it's in `mcp.field_editor.php` and `libraries/Package_installer.php`. Delete those lines. It's not necessary for newer versions of EE.

I do not know if there are any other issues with Field Editor and EE 2.8, but this should clear up this particular issue.

Comment: Just tried this out. Perfect. Was able to edit fields again using Field Editor, yay!